# Has anyone every had to limit the number of memberships (of a specific type) that can be sold?

Tags: civimember

Project for swim club: offering kids' swim lessons in different pools + different time/slots. The program sells out quickly so need maximum number of spots available; recurring contribution - monthly payments.

I'm leaning towards looking at this as Membership (with one Membership Type per Pool/time/slot combination). Has anyone every had to limit the number of memberships (of a specific type) that can be sold? Trying to figure out the path of least resistance :-)

Comment: Still curious if anyone has had a need to do this - but I'm going to try and look at it from the Event angle - as I do like the waitlist option that FrTommy reminded me off. So an Event - where a Parent can sign up a Kid for a specific Pool/Time slot - AND start a recurring contribution for the balance due to be paid over 9 months. I should have enough knowledge of recurring contributions to figure that out! On it.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds more like civiEvents would work better. You can limit the number of spots(attendees) and even have waitlists. You could set your price set up to be a recurring contribution for the Event.

Comment: How do you set up recurring contribution on an Event registration page?

Comment: Hmm, I thought there was a way. I just tried it and apparently not. I seem to remember there was some discussion about this at one point. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: I think that may have been about recording partial payments towards an Event registraiton - but not about actually setting up a recurring series [which would be able to trigger the payments].

Comment: possibly. I think I would still use civiEvents for this use case and then just go in and manually set up a recurring contribution for those people who registered.

Comment: For a recurring series - you need to tokenize the credit card right away - or you'd have to contact everyone [and that's a lot of parents].

Comment: +1 for using CiviEvent. You can also define event templates if you're in the habit of creating a lot of similar events.